# Dependant SubQuery v Left Join

Tags: mysql

This query displays the correct result but when doing an EXPLAIN, it lists it as a "Dependant SubQuery" which I'm led to believe is bad?

```
SELECT Competition.CompetitionID, Competition.CompetitionName,     Competition.CompetitionStartDate  
FROM Competition  
WHERE CompetitionID NOT   
IN (  
SELECT CompetitionID  
FROM PicksPoints  
WHERE UserID =1    
)
```

I tried changing the query to this:

```
SELECT Competition.CompetitionID, Competition.CompetitionName,   Competition.CompetitionStartDate  
FROM Competition  
LEFT JOIN PicksPoints ON Competition.CompetitionID = PicksPoints.CompetitionID  
WHERE UserID =1  
and PicksPoints.PicksPointsID is null
```

but it displays 0 rows. What is wrong with the above compared to the first query that actually does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seconds query cannot produce rows: it claims:

```
WHERE UserID =1  
and PicksPoints.PicksPointsID is null
```

But to clarify, I rewrite as follows:

```
WHERE PicksPoints.UserID =1  
and PicksPoints.PicksPointsID is null
```

So, on one hand, you are asking for rows on `PicksPoints` where `UserId = 1`, but then again you expect the row to not exist in the first place. Can you see the fail?

External joins are so tricky at that! Usually you filter using columns from the "outer" table, for example `Competition`. But you do not wish to do so; you wish to filter on the left-joined table. Try and rewrite as follows:

```
SELECT Competition.CompetitionID, Competition.CompetitionName,   Competition.CompetitionStartDate  
FROM Competition  
LEFT JOIN PicksPoints ON (Competition.CompetitionID = PicksPoints.CompetitionID AND UserID = 1)
WHERE 
PicksPoints.PicksPointsID is null
```

For more on this, read this [nice post](http://www.mysqldiary.com/mysql-left-join/).

But, as an additional note, performance-wise you're in some trouble, using either subquery or the left join.

With subquery you're in trouble because up to **5.6** (where some good work has been done), MySQL is very bad with optimizing inner queries, and your subquery is expected to execute multiple times.

With the `LEFT JOIN` you are in trouble since a `LEFT JOIN` dictates the order of join from left to right. Yet your filtering is on the right table, which means you will not be able to use an index for filtering the `USerID = 1` condition (or you would, and lose the index for the join).

Comment: +1 Great link and good advice about performance issues, but don't you think that `UserId <> 1` is a better translation of the OP's first query?

Comment: `UserId <> 1` might work well. I'm not sure which is clearer (or less obfuscated :) )

Answer (score 0):

These are two different queries. The first query looks for competitions associated with user id 1 (via the `PicksPoints` table), which the second joins with those rows that *are* associated with user id 1 that in addition have a null `PicksPointsID`.

The second query is coming out empty because you are joining against a table called `PicksPoints` and you are looking for rows in the join result that have `PicksPointsID` as null.  This can only happen if

1. The second table had a row with a null `PickPointsID` *and* a competition id that matched a competition id in the first table, or
2. *All* the columns in the second table's contribution to the join are null because there is a competition id in the first table that did not appear in the second.

Since `PicksPointsID` really sounds like a primary key, it's case 2 that is showing up.  So all the columns from `PickPointsID` are null, your where clause (`UserID=1 and PicksPoints.PicksPointsID is null`) will always be false and your result will be empty.

A plain left join should work for you

```
select c.CompetitionID, c.CompetitionName, c.CompetitionStartDate  
from Competition c
left join PicksPoints p
on (c.CompetitionID = p.CompetitionID)
where p.UserID <> 1
```

Replacing the final `where` with an `and` (making a complex join clause) might also work.  I'll leave it to you to analyze the plans for each query. :)

I'm not personally convinced of the need for the `is null` test.  The article linked to by Shlomi Noach is excellent and you may find some tips in there to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can do the first query within the "IN"?